# Wordpress javascript file call returns strange path

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to includ jQuery and my custom script file in a Wordpress Child theme using the recommended method `wp_enqueue_script`

```
<?php

function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()  
{  
    // Register the script like this for a plugin:  
    wp_register_script( 'customScripts', plugins_url( '/js/customScripts.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );  
    // or  
    // Register the script like this for a theme:  
    wp_register_script( 'customScripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customScripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );  
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customScripts' );  
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' ); 

?>
```

This works fine including jQuery, but it spits out this path for my custom script.

```
http://localhost:15869/wp-content/plugins/C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/MyWebSites/TomWictor.com/wp-content/themes/twentywelve-child/js/customScripts.js?ver=3.5
```

This is obviously wrong. I don't think it has anything to do with developing on a localhost (using Microsoft WebMatrix 2) but more to do with the way Wordpress deciphers paths? I am not sure..

How can I get it to spit out the proper path?

```
twentywelve-child/js/customScripts.js
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `plugins_url( 'js/customScripts.js', __FILE__ )` instead of `plugins_url( '/js/customScripts.js', __FILE__ )` (remove your first slash)

Look: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url